# Erro: EntityManager is closed

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Meu sistema de comandas, no momento de tentar mesclar mesas, utilizo o EntityManager.merge, porém ocorre o seguinte erro: EntityManager is closed.

Segue uma das funções do meu código que ocorre esse erro:

```
public boolean trocar_Mesa(BigDecimal origem, BigDecimal destino,String usuario) {
    ok = true;
    mensagem = "";

    Tab_Log_Troca_Mesa oMesa = null;
    Tab_Mesas oMesaOri = null;
    Tab_Mesas oMesaDest = null;
    Calendar hoje = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateTime agora = new DateTime();

    EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();

    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        for (Tab_Comanda oComanda : (new Tab_ComandaDao())
                .listar_ComandasMesas(origem)) {
            oComanda.setNumero_Mesa(destino);
            em.merge(oComanda);
        }
```

Segue também a função JavaScript listar_ComandasMesas caso possa ajudar, mas pelo que percebi ela está retornando corretamente a lista, acredito que o erro não esteja nela...

```
public List<Tab_Comanda> listar_ComandasMesas(BigDecimal mesa)
{
    List<Tab_Comanda> oLista = null;
    ok = true;
    mensagem = "";

    String sql = 
        "select * from TAB_COMANDAS where NUMERO_MESA = :pNumeroMesa";
    EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();;

    try
    {
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql, Tab_Comanda.class);
        query.setParameter("pNumeroMesa", mesa);
        oLista = query.getResultList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        ok = false;
        mensagem = ex.getMessage();
    }
    finally{
        if (em.isOpen()){
            em.close();
        }
    }
    return oLista;
}
```

Não encontrei nenhum fórum que pudesse me ajudar e estou começando agora no JavaWEB, alguém já se deparou com esse problema e/ou sabe como resolvê-lo?

Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 1):

Ao usar o merge você precisa usa o mesmo EntityManager que você usou pra carregar a entidade, mas como você fechou esse EM logo depois de listar, esse erro ocorre. Agora você precisa usar o find pra carregar esse objeto e copiar as propriedades novas dele para salvar.

Comment: Então Julio, obrigado pela dica, mas eu tinha esquecido de citar o seguinte... Eu já rodava essa aplicação com um banco SQLServer e funcionava normalmente, aí fiz a conversão desse banco para MySQL, fiz os ajustes necessários na aplicação para conectar no banco MySQL, e simplesmente parou de funcionar essa parte... Saberia como me ajudar?

Comment: Bom cara, pelo que eu sei esse erro ocorre independente de banco de dados, se funcionava antes, então eu não saberia te ajudar, espero que alguém mais apareça pra tentar resolver.

Comment: Ah beleza então... Mesmo assim, vou ver se entendi e tentar fazer o que você me passou, resolvendo meu problema é o que importa kkkkk Obrigado.